# Rails: Cannot use methods defined in application helper within devise email views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, view, devise, helper

I created some sort of mini cms, and I am trying to call a function 
called render_content within the email confirmation view, but it just 
won't take it :( 
Alway complaining the method does not exist ? 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here... 
Alex

Comment: Which rails version are you using?

Comment: rails 3.0.3 sorry forgot to specify

Answer (score 4):

Well after a while I figured it out, if the helper is located in the Application Helper, then this call will work:

```
ApplicationController.helpers.render_content()
```

Alex